# Does webapp2 provide some mechanism to invoke DELETE and PUT actions form html forms

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

Given the following routes:

```
Route(r'/app/product/<id:\d+>', handler='app.handlers.ProductHandler:show', 
methods=['GET'], name='show-product'), 
Route(r'/app/product/<id:\d+>', 
handler='app.handlers.ProductHandler:delete', methods=['DELETE'], 
name='delete-product'),
```

and the following form:

```
<form action="{{ uri_for('delete-product', id=product.key.id()) }}" 
method="DELETE">
```

Submitting this form is picked up by show-product route.

DELETE and PUT actions are not supported by most browsers, but many web 
frameworks support some magic to support them anyway. E.g. providing a 
hidden _method param.

Does webapp2 has something to support DELETE and PUT actions out of the box?

Comment: Yes it does have a look here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webapp2 can receive this methods, but no any magic to support this params in browsers.

Comment: Yes that's why I thought. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively simple to add this functionality in to WebApp2.

This decorator looks for a value in the `http_verb` parameter and, if found, calls the appropriate request handler method.

```
def spoof_rest(func):
    """ Decorator to handle spoofing RESTful verbs """
    def inner(handler):
        params = handler.request.params
        if 'http_verb' in params:
            if params['http_verb'] == 'PUT':
                handler.put()
            elif params['http_verb'] == 'DELETE':
                handler.delete()
    return inner


class MyRoute(RequestHandler):

    @spoof_rest
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("GET request")

    @spoof_rest
    def post(self):
        self.response.write("POST request")

    def put(self):
        self.response.write("PUT request")

    def delete(self):
        self.response.write("DELETE request")
```